# How can I combine 10 amp current from solar panel with power from the national grid?

Tags: solar-energy

I want 10 amp current into my load.

I want my solar panel to provide as much as it can, but the remaining should come from national grid. How can I combine these two currents into one unified 10 amp current?

Comment: I removed the unrelated tags.

Comment: Please be aware that current is *related* to power, but it isn't power.  Current *at* some voltage is an expression of power (i.e. "10A at 220V").

Comment: what happens when clouds cover the sun?

Comment: You haven't given any indication of the voltage of the solar panel or the load.  That makes a big difference to any possible answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a grid-tie inverter from your solar array.  Check your local laws to see what you need to do to be legal, and your local electricians for what you need to do to be safe.